# How do I decide the font and font size of my ebook?

Tags: fonts

I am self-publishing my ebook on my own website. I currently have the manuscript in MS word. Now, for the final publication in PDF format how do I decide upon the font and font size of the book content?

Comment: Related question: https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/7651/pdf-e-book-page-size-and-fonts

Comment: NB You might want to consider an e-book format that allows users to change their font size, such as [EPUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB). You can do [multiple formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats), of course.

Answer (score 3):

[How to Format a Manuscript for Self-publishing](https://jerryjenkins.com/format-manuscript-for-self-publishing/) has some advice on book formatting (you can probably find more).

If you can, use any e-book format *other than* PDF. (Check out the link.) Other formats will allow the reader and the user to select font and font size and will have a default setting (in most cases configurable by the reader).

Places like Amazon will likely also enforce using their format (mobi, if I remember correctly).

If, on the other hand, you're formatting a PDF for print, use Jerry Jenkin's advice for print formatting. [10 Best Fonts to Make Your Book Look Like a Bestseller](https://swatt-books.co.uk/10-best-fonts-look-like-bestseller) has a page on fonts, but generally, printed text should have serifs.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't obsess over this. Use a reasonably normal font size, like somewhere between 11 point and 14 point. Unless this book is intended to be read by people with vision problems. Use a normal-looking font. Not something excessively decorative or unusual. Because the novelty of an unusual font will quickly wear off and then it will just be annoying and hard to read.